# Restart program and lost data in database

Tags: c#

I have data in 'mdf' database, which I'm not allowed to come.
But every time I restart the program the data is lost? Why?

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;
con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
                        AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Jirka\Project_26\databaze.mdf;
                        Integrated Security=True";
con.Open();
con.Close();
```

Comment: "not allowed to come"?

Comment: Could you please add more detail to the question your asking?

Comment: I added a click event on the button (CLICK).

In another part of the program, I loaded the data into the database. And if I click on a button (CLICK) and opens a connection to the database, listing the message and end the connection and everything is OK.

But if I run the application again, so the database is empty. Although I do it recorded data.

Comment: You only open /close the connection where's  the code where you perform data operations?

Comment: Is the database file included in the project, and set to "Copy always"?

Comment: Copy to Output Directory: Copy if Newer.

Answer (score 3):

If 'every time I restart the program' mean every time you run it in visual studio, then your problem is that the database is copied on every compile.

Select the Copy if newer option instead and try then.

[image]

Comment: Yes I have this set. The problem persists.

Comment: So i record the video.  [VIDEO](https://vid.me/qaBA)

>1. start - load the data to database and exit the program
>2. start - control the load data (OK), click to button and execute this code and close aplication [CODE](http://paste.ofcode.org/hhRbc2ETU6VrNYPPSsXxUq)
>3. start - data is lost

Comment: Are you sure you are saving the information to the database? and not just updating the table?

Comment: Really good, straight to the point answer, thank you @ThomasAndreèLian