# SQLite database not saving data Once the Windows Form app stops

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite

I have been attempting to use SQLite database for a Winform C# Project.

The .db file is saved in my project directory and my code has access to it fine. If I enter the value, it works, if I enter the same it errors, as it should.

Once I stop the Windows Form Program and Start it again, all the data I entered is cleared.

- Question - How can I ensure the data in the .db file is saved. I guess there's a setting I'm missing.

```
 using (SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
            {
                cnn.Open();
                using (SQLiteTransaction transaction = cnn.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(cnn))
                    {
                        SQLiteParameter IDParam = new SQLiteParameter();
                        SQLiteParameter NameParam = new SQLiteParameter();
                      

                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into Person (ID, Name) VALUES (@ID, @Name)";
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", 1);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", "Lewis");

                        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    transaction.Commit();
                    //cnn.Execute("insert into Person (ID, Name) values (1, 'Lewis')", person)                    
                    
                }
            }
```

Code for reference.

Comment: Have you checked the modified date on the .db file after the first insert? Is it possibly you're copying over the file when you re-run the app?

Comment: I noticed I have my .db file in the same directory as my Project, and that's what my connectionstring is pointing to. I also have the same db file within the Debug folder of the project, and that is the file getting updated.

New Question, how can I use the file in the Debug within the solution or why don't they both update equally.

Comment: Probable duplicate: [Restart program and lost data in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29681943/restart-program-and-lost-data-in-database)

Comment: When I Insert data, yes it gets saved into the following db: SQLLite\WindowsFormsApp1\bin\Debug\DemoDB.db" however my app.config file uses the connection string <add name="Default" connectionString="Data Source= .\DemoDB.db;Version=3" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> so when I do a select it retrieves nothing.

Comment: Maybe try to modify the connection string to `Data Source=DemoDB.db`.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**

Add the Sqlite database via the tool.